# What is alternative API for posix_fallocate

Tags: android, linux, filesystems, kernel, libc

I'm working on a customized android target board. The board file system is mounted over NFS. There is a API call procedure `Libcore.os.posix_fallocate` which tries to create length of a physical file, but the operation failed due to "Error:Operation not supported on the transport endpoint". My immediate guess would be that `posix_fallocate` cannot be operated over NFS and I googled around seem my guess is valid. So is there any alternative API I can use to operate the same result?

It looks I can use `dd` command to pre-create a file, if that's the case, what API did `dd` command actually calling? I guess I can steal the API from `dd`

Answer (score 0):

ftruncate can replace it, it does not take offset parameter

Comment: While `ftruncate` will set the size it will not necessarily allocate the space, instead leaving it as a sparse file (if supported by the filesystem).  `fallocate` fully realizes the file and checks against disk-full now instead of when the bytes are actually written.